# AWS Lambda function, secret manager cannot get secret value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function to send billing reports to certain email addresses, for that im using my email address and app password. I have saved the app password under secret manager as other api. When i try to retrieve it using the lambda function it shows error.

```
import boto3
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import ast
import os
import datetime
import base64
import logging
import collections
import json

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def get_secret():

    secret_name = "email_app_password"
    region_name = "ca-central-1"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    # See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    # We rethrow the exception by default.

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            # An error occurred on the server side.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
            
    # Your code goes here. 


def send_email(email_body):
    """
    Sends email according to environment variables.
    :param email_body: Body of email.
    :return: None
    """
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    email = os.environ['EMAIL_FROM']
    try:
        secret_value = get_secret()
        print(secret_value[os.environ['SECRET_KEY_NAME']])
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Exception while trying to get password from Secrets Manager")
        return
    sec_key = os.environ['SECRET_KEY_NAME']
    password = ast.literal_eval(secret_value)[os.environ['SECRET_KEY_NAME']]
    msg['Subject'] = os.environ["EMAIL_SUBJECT"]
    msg['From'] = email
    you = os.environ['EMAIL_TO'].split(',')
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(you)
    body = email_body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
    try:
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        smtpObj.starttls()
        smtpObj.login(email, password)
        smtpObj.sendmail(email, you, msg.as_string())
        smtpObj.quit()
        logger.info('Email sent')
    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        logger.info("Error: unable to send email due to %s", e)


class FileOpener:
    """
    Class to cache file contents.
    """
    file_cache = {}

    @staticmethod
    def open_file(filename):
        if filename not in FileOpener.file_cache:
            with open(filename) as fp:
                FileOpener.file_cache[filename] = fp.read()
        return FileOpener.file_cache[filename]


def get_account_cost(account_no, start_day, end_day):
    client = boto3.client('ce')
    response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={
            'Start': start_day,
            'End': end_day
        },
        Granularity='MONTHLY',
        Filter={
            "And": [{
                "Dimensions": {
                    "Key": "LINKED_ACCOUNT",
                    "Values": [account_no]
                }
            }, {
                "Not": {
                    "Dimensions": {
                        "Key": "RECORD_TYPE",
                        "Values": ["Credit", "Refund"]
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        Metrics=["BlendedCost"],
        GroupBy=[
            {
                'Type': 'DIMENSION',
                'Key': 'SERVICE'
            },
        ]
    )
    cost_dictionary = collections.Counter()
    for result in response['ResultsByTime']:
        for group in result['Groups']:
            servicename = group['Keys'][0]
            amount = round(float(group['Metrics']['BlendedCost']['Amount']), 2)
            if amount == 0.0:
                continue
            cost_dictionary[servicename] += amount
    return cost_dictionary


def combine_cost_dictionaries(prev_cost_dict, curr_cost_dict):
    combined_cost_dict = {}
    prev_cost_total = 0.0
    curr_cost_total = 0.0
    for service, curr_cost in curr_cost_dict.items():
        prev_cost = 0.0
        if service in prev_cost_dict:
            prev_cost = prev_cost_dict[service]
        combined_cost_dict[service] = (prev_cost, curr_cost)
        prev_cost_total += prev_cost
        curr_cost_total += curr_cost
    for service, prev_cost in prev_cost_dict.items():
        curr_cost = 0.0
        if service not in combined_cost_dict:
            combined_cost_dict[service] = (prev_cost, curr_cost)
            prev_cost_total += prev_cost
            curr_cost_total += curr_cost
    return combined_cost_dict, prev_cost_total, curr_cost_total


def generate_account_cost_html(account_name, combined_cost_dict, prev_cost_total, curr_cost_total):
    prev_date = str((datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=2)))
    curr_date = str((datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)))
    table_rows = ""
    sorted_combined_cost = sorted(combined_cost_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)
    for service, costs in sorted_combined_cost:
        table_row = FileOpener.open_file("table_row.html")
        prev_cost = round(float(costs[0]), 2)
        curr_cost = round(float(costs[1]), 2)
        if prev_cost < 0.01:
            percentage_change = 'New Charge'
        else:
            percentage_change = ((curr_cost - prev_cost) / prev_cost) * 100
            percentage_change = round(float(percentage_change), 2)
            if percentage_change > 0:
                percentage_change = "↑ {}%".format(percentage_change)
            elif percentage_change == 0.0:
                percentage_change = "{}%".format(percentage_change)
            else:
                percentage_change = "↓ {}%".format(percentage_change)
        if percentage_change[0] == '↑':
            percentage_css = "background-color: pink;border:darkblue solid thin;"
        elif percentage_change == 'New Charge':
            percentage_css = "background-color: LightGreen;border:darkblue solid thin;"
        else:
            percentage_css = "border:lightblue solid thin;"
        table_rows += table_row.format(service, prev_cost, curr_cost, percentage_css, percentage_change)

    prev_cost_total = round(float(prev_cost_total), 2)
    curr_cost_total = round(float(curr_cost_total), 2)
    table = FileOpener.open_file("table.html")
    table = table.format(account_name, prev_cost_total, curr_cost_total, prev_date, curr_date, table_rows)
    return table


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    account_names = os.environ['ACCOUNT_NAMES'].split(",")
    account_numbers = os.environ['ACCOUNT_NUMBERS'].split(",")
    table_body_html = ''
    for account_name, account_no in zip(account_names, account_numbers):
        day_1 = str((datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=2)))
        day_2 = str((datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)))
        day_3 = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
        prev_cost_dict = get_account_cost(account_no, day_1, day_2)
        curr_cost_dict = get_account_cost(account_no, day_2, day_3)
        combined_cost_dict, prev_cost_total, curr_cost_total = combine_cost_dictionaries(prev_cost_dict, curr_cost_dict)
        table_body = generate_account_cost_html(account_name, combined_cost_dict, prev_cost_total, curr_cost_total)
        table_body_html += table_body
    email_body = FileOpener.open_file("email_body.html").format(table_body_html)
    send_email(email_body)
```

I get the following error when running the lambda function. I have even tried removing the print line. Then the error goes to password = ast.literal_eval(secret_value)[os.environ['SECRET_KEY_NAME']]

```
[ERROR] 2022-08-18T06:02:03.968Z    2ae88ceb-39a6-4feb-aa7c-2cbb17ec655c    Exception while trying to get password from Secrets Manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 88, in send_email
    print(secret_value[os.environ['SECRET_KEY_NAME']])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptableEND RequestId: 2ae88ceb-39a6-4feb-aa7c-2cbb17ec655c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your get_secret function does not return the value to the calling code.  Please edit the else clause:

```
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS key.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            return get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            return base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this as well, non-intuitive error, when I did this:

```
except ClientError as e:
   print(f"exception: {e}")
```

It became very clear what the issue was, I needed to add secrets manager permissions to the permissions boundary for the executing role.

I hope that helps someone.